# Cannot find name 'it' in Jest TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm, jestjs, ts-jest

I try to create an intial setup for Jest in React + TypeScript. I have completed the initial setup and try to check whether the test runs.
When I run the test using the command `npm test`, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
```

I have installed the types for Jest as well as removed the types in `tsconfig.json`, but still I am getting the same error.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin" }],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "pretty": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "types": ["jest"],
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "node_modules/@types/jest"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
`
```

Package.json

```
    "jest": {
        "transform": {
          ".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest"
        },
        "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "ts",
          "tsx",
          "js"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.3",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.14",
        "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
        "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
        "husky": "^2.2.0",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "prettier": "^1.17.0",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
        "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
        "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.2.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
        "stylelint-order": "^0.8.1",
        "stylelint-scss": "^3.1.3",
        "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
        "tslint": "^5.16.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
        "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
        "tslint-react": "^4.0.0",
        "tslint-react-hooks": "^2.1.0"
      }
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Install**

```
npm install -D jest @types/jest ts-jest
```

**jest.config.js -- at root**

```json
 module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     ...

      "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],
      "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
     
     ...
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
  }
```

Comment: I had `@types/jest, `"types": ["jest"], and `"typeRoots": ["./types"]` in the tsconfig and wasn't working. I only changed `typeRoots` to be `"typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]` and it worked with no other changes

Answer (score 36):

Import this in any of your test files:

```
import '@types/jest';
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I don't know why. And I don't want to import it EVERY time.

Comment: Saviour of mankind. This makes me problems in monorepos like lerna, because of the hoisting nature of lerna.

Comment: @ConAntonakos I was able to just place this import in my `react-app-env.d.ts` and it filtered down for all my test files.

Comment: @ajbieber You rock. I am going to try that. <3

Comment: You can install the `@types/jest` package instead of importing it. This is better anyway as it makes the dependency explicit and works with all package managers.

Answer (score 27):

For me, the problem was that my `tsconfig.json` was built with

```
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
```

I had to change that to

```
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ]
```

(My tests all being in directory 'tests')

Comment: This will include tests folder in the output directory which is not ideal

Comment: @schystz I agree that this is not ideal but so far it's been the only way to get my tests not to make eslint go crazy. I also tried moving my __tests__ folder into my src folder, hoping that somehow inheritance would allow the jest types to be found but the exclude would keep it from being in the output. Alas, no. If anyone else has any advice, I'd take it.

Comment: You can add a "child" config  for tests: ./test/tsconfig.json `{ "extends": "../tsconfig.json", "include": ["../src/**/*", "**/*"] }` like https://github.com/cloudflare/miniflare-typescript-esbuild-jest/blob/master/test/tsconfig.json

Comment: Didn't see this answer below, which answers your question @H Johnson https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773251/2586761

Answer (score 24):

In tsconfig.json add the below code

```
"types": ["jest"],
"typeRoots": ["./src/types", "node_modules/@types"],
```

Comment: I didn't need to use line 2

Comment: Funny, I didn't need the first line. Adding `node_modules/@types` to `typeRoots` resolved the issue for me

Comment: first one did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: May you explain a bit why these two lines are required? Why this wouldn't be default config of typescript?

Answer (score 24):

I had to add `"@types/jest"` to my `"types"` array in my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Yes! Had to be `@types/jest`, not just `jest` as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

I've tried all the above solutions, but unfortunately, none of them worked out for me. The solution that worked in my case though was to reference the type definitions via `/// <reference types="@types/jest" />;` at the top of the file. You need to install `@types/jest` package first. The downside to it is that you have to import it into all the files.

Comment: Tried everything else; this was it for me.

Comment: God I hate Jest and its inconceivable configuration soup. Nothing else worked except this. Okay. Glad I can move on to actually productive things.

Comment: For me, installing @types/jest and then adding '@types/jest' to 'types' in my tsconfig.json meant I didn't need to add it to every file

Answer (score 6):

Install @types/jest `npm install @types/jest` and add config for jest:

```json
// package.json
// ...
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "path_to_our_tests/jest.tsconfig.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Create jest.tsconfig.json in your test directory and adjust like this:

```json
// path_to_our_tests/jest.tsconfig.json"
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["../src", "**/*"]
}
```

Ensure that your root tsconfig only includes src files, not test files:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This way you don't change the global configs of your project, and prevents breaking your code.

Both configs should pass a compiler check:

`npx tsc && npx tsc -p path_to_our_tests/jest.tsconfig.json`

Comment: In my case, my root tsconfig had no "include" field, so it was checking my tests/* directory as well... adding `"include": "src"` completed the setup for me 

Comment: Updated your answer to add detail around `include` and compiler checking - hope you don't mind! Inspired by https://github.com/cloudflare/miniflare-typescript-esbuild-jest/blob/master/test/tsconfig.json

Comment: This is absolutely the most complete and easiest answer!

Answer (score 1):

Updating `ts-loader` to `v6.0.1` or above can do a trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install jest in the devDependency:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jest
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Not even importing '@types/jest' which was throwing error while doing npm test to import 'jest' instead. The only solution for me is import { describe, it, beforeEach } from '@jest/globals' to test files

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the output of `npx ts-jest config:init` (as suggested [in the ts-jest documentation](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#getting-started)) I discovered that adding this line to the top of my `jest.config.js` file did the trick:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed and configured modern versions of Jest and TypeScript, you should only need to install `@types/jest` with your package manager to fix this error:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jest
pnpm add --save-dev @types/jest
yarn add --dev @types/jest
bun add --dev @types/jest
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem was that I actually didn't have a `jest` folder in my `./node_modules/@types` directory. Running `npm i @types/jest` claimed that the package was `up to date` but it still didn't exist in my `node_modules/@types` where it should be installed so the error persisted.

I fixed the issue by installing `@types/jest` globally and copying the installed package to my `./node_modules/@types`.

To install `@jest/types` globally run:

```sh
npm i -g @types/jest
```

To get the path to your global node_modules run:

```sh
npm root -g
```

To confirm that the `@types/jest` package is there run:

```sh
ls $(npm root -g)/@types
```

Then cd into your project directory and run

```sh
cp -R $(npm root -g)/@types/jest ./node_modules/@types
```

to copy it to your local node_modules.