# ts-jest trouble with unit testing

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions, ts-jest

Trying to unit test firebase cloud functions using `ts-jest`, but having trouble with a simple test.

I've installed jest for typescript, typings, and ts-jest config but I'm getting an error that says `@types/jest` isn't installed.

**main.test.ts**

```
/// <reference types="jest" />

import { database } from '../src/firestore';

test('Firestore is initialized', () => {
    expect(database).toBeDefined();
});
```

**error message:** Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.ts(2582)

**version:** `@types/jest@24.0.19`

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules and doing npm i?

Comment: Tried that already, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I fixed my issue this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463822/4298218, maybe that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that the configuration in your project is not finished at all, I followed the [quickstart for firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), deployed to my project and then installed the dependencies using:

> npm install jest @types/jest firebase-functions-test ts-jest -D

Added the test script to my package.json

> "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose=false"

and finally configured jest (jest.config.js) in my project (at my functions directory)

```
// this config includes typescript specific settings
// and if you're not using typescript, you should remove `transform` property
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    testRegex: 'src(/testing/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['lib/', 'node_modules/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    rootDir: 'src',
}
```

After all of this, I created a testing directory inside function/src folder and wrote a simple test like this inside testing

```
test("should pass", () => {
    // test test lol
    expect(1).toBe(1);
});
```

Finally, you can take a look at my package.json file if you have any other doubts about the dependencies I used.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose=false"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hi @chinoche, my project configuration matches the above and I'm still getting the same typescript error ‍♀️

Comment: Uhm, I'm not quite sure what could be causing this error in your dev environment, I've created a [small repo](https://github.com/chinoche/fjestest), you could clone it and test it in your environment to discard if this is an environment issue or if this is related with the project's configuration